# Some details about adjusting cascaded AdaBoost stage threshold

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, machine-learning, computer-vision, pattern-recognition

I have implemented AdaBoost sequence algorithm and currently I am trying to implement so called Cascaded AdaBoost, basing on P. Viola and M. Jones original paper. Unfortunately I have some doubts, connected with adjusting the threshold for one stage. As we can read in original paper, the procedure is described in literally one sentence:

```
Decrease threshold for the ith classiﬁer until the current
cascaded classiﬁer has a detection rate of at least
d × Di − 1 (this also affects Fi)
```

I am not sure mainly two things:

- What is the threshold? Is it 0.5 * sum (alpha) expression value or only 0.5 factor?
- What should be the initial value of the threshold? (0.5?)
- What does "decrease threshold" mean in details? Do I need to iterative select new threshold e.g. 0.5, 0.4, 0.3? What is the step of decreasing?

I have tried to search this info in Google, but unfortunately I could not find any useful information.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same doubt and have not found any authoritative source so far. However, this is what is my best guess to this issue:
1. (0.5*sum(aplha)) is the threshold.
2. Initial value of the threshold is what is above. Next, try to classify the samples using the intermediate strong classifier (what you currently have). You'll get the scores each of the samples attain, and depending on the current value of threshold, some of the positive samples will be classified as negative etc. So, depending on the desired detection rate desired for this stage (strong classifier), reduce the threshold so that that many positive samples get correctly classified ,

eg:
say thresh. was 10, and these are the current classifier outputs for positive training samples:

9.5, 10.5, 10.2, 5.4, 6.7

and I want a detection rate of 80% => 80% of above 5 samples classified correctly => 4 of above => set threshold to 6.7

Clearly, by changing the threshold, the FP rate also changes, so update that, and if the desired FP rate for the stage not reached, go for another classifier at that stage.

I have not done a formal course on ada-boost etc, but this is my observation based on some research papers I tried to implement. Please correct me if something is wrong. Thanks!

Comment: what is 9.5, 10.5, 10.2, 5.4, 6.7 ? please extend your answer.

Comment: those values are the accumulated responses from the individual weak classifiers in the current stage weighted by their corresponding alphas. For example if you have 4 weak classifier with the alphas (1, 2.5, 3, 4) this means for the first positive sample that all but the first classified the sample as 1 (hence 9.5) and for the second sample all answered 1 (hence 10.5). Obviously those alphas are not sufficient to explain the other values but it should be clear how the values are computed with more weak classifiers.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a Master thesis on real-time face detection by Karim Ayachi ([pdf](http://www.science.uva.nl/research/ias/alumni/m.sc.theses/theses/KarimAyachi.pdf)) in which he describes the Viola Jones face detection method.

As it is written in Section 5.2 (Creating the Cascade using AdaBoost), we can set the maximal threshold of the strong classifier to sum(alpha) and the minimal threshold to 0 and then find the optimal threshold using binary search (see Table 5.1 for pseudocode).

Hope this helps!